# Apache Error: While writing python logs into file outside the project directory

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, apache2.4

I am working on a Django project and using Apache as web server. Everything is working fine with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But while running the application through apache I am not able to write my python app logs into the stated path which is outside the project directory.

Project directory `/home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing`

Log files are in

`/home/ubuntu/log/SaasAap/SaasAap.log` and `/home/ubuntu/log/error/error.log`

My `000-default.conf` content

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerAdmin abc@xyz.com
        ServerName my_ip
        ServerAlias my_ip
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing/src/wsgi.py
        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing/static/
        ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/log/error.log
        CustomLog /home/ubuntu/log/custom.log combined
        <Location "/static/">
                Options -Indexes
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
        </Location>
        <Location "/">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Location>
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing/static>
                Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
        </Directory>
         <Directory /home/ubuntu/log>
                Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess saas-DocumentProcessing python-path=/home/ubuntu/
saas-DocumentProcessing python-home=/home/ubuntu/saas-DocumentProcessing/ve
nv
        WSGIProcessGroup saas-DocumentProcessing

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does apache has appropriate permission to that directory ?

Comment: Yes, Apache has all have the permission to the log directory.